# How to get the name of an object through the template_tag?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, templatetags

i want to pass the name of an object through a template tag but i got this error:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'mymodelone_set'
```

My models:

```
class mymodelone(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    show = models.ForeignKey('mymodeltwo')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class mymodeltwo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

my template tag looks like this:

In my base.html:

```
{% load my_tags %}{% my_func obj%}
```

In my model_tag.py

```
register = template.Library()
@register.inclusion_tag('myapp/widget.html')
def my_func(obj):
    param1 = obj.mymodelone_set.all()
return {}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is `objectName` a string? Please show the underlying view.

Comment: Hi @alecxe i wrote it bad, i edit the question, my intention is to write in the tag the name of the object directly, is it possible?. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: @palafox_e Actually we wanted to see your view code like Where that `obj` came from ...?

Comment: Following up on what @alexce and raja-simon are asking and your own response, it sounds like you are passing the name of the class (or similar) as a string rather than an actual instance. So obj contains a string which has no mymodelone_set method or variable. The code in model_tag.py expects an instance.

Comment: I haven´t another view, following your advice i try to get the obj string value to make a query but I can see in my local vars that obj value is ' '

Comment: What do you mean, you don't have a view? Of course you have a view, otherwise what's rendering your template? We need to see the view.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you for answering, i think its maybe not the best aproach to do what i am triyng to acomplish but i make it work. See, i have a model, and i want to render it on a template, but i dont want to use a for tag in the template, i would rather preffer to use the name of the object that i want to show in the template_tag. The problem was that i wasn't getting the obj parameter from the template. I have registered a simple_tag to get the obj parameter and now it works as expected. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

```
class mymodelone(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    show = models.ForeignKey('mymodeltwo')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class mymodeltwo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

You had inverted your self.name/self.title in the wrong class, at least that's what it looks like to me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use your template tag like

```
@register.filter
def my_func(obj):
    return obj.__class__.__name__
```

use it in your template as:

```
{{ obj | my_func }}
```